# jPlayer 2.9.2 seek / play time not working in Firefox?

Tags: position, jplayer, seek

this does not work for me in recent firefox (desktop, only tested on osx):

```
$("#jpId").jPlayer("play", 42); // seek 42sec. not working
$("#jpId").jPlayer("play"); // works
```

it simply does nothing. [test case here](http://aporee.org/test/jplayer.html).
ideas appreciated.

edit: 
workaround is

```
// load sound and start play without time, then again with time. odd. 
$("#jpId").jPlayer("play");
$("#jpId").jPlayer("play", 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("#jpId").jPlayer("play", 42);
}, 100);
```

> **CAUSE**

Call `setTimeoout` is needed because according to the documentation for [`play`](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play) method:

> If issued immediately after a `setMedia` command, with the `time` parameter, and when the browser is using the HTML5 solution, this command will initially fail and an internal timeout is setup to retry the command every 100ms until it succeeds.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecskh7y8/) for demonstration.

Comment: doesn't work. I think you've misinterpreted the docs. jplayer kicks an internal timeout automatically. but it doesn't succeed...

Comment: @unosonic, I know that it looks that I misinterpreted the docs but when I tried `play` without `setTimeout`, it didn't look like jplayer tries to retry with `setTimeout` internally so I try to forcefully do it myself. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecskh7y8/) for demonstration.

Comment: yes, jPlayer("play", <time>) works when issued in an event or setMedia was called before in another context. It fails when called directly after setMedia, That's what the docs mention, but this internal timeout doesn't seem to work. Anyway, workaround is possible... thanks.